# sum columns of part of 2D array Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, sum

INPUT:

```
M = [[1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]]
```

how take the sum of the columns in the two first rows and implement it in the array M

OUTPUT:

```
M = [[2,4,6],
    [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code for you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Use `numpy.add.reduceat`:

```
import numpy as np
M = [[1,2,3],
    [1,2,3],
    [1,2,3]]

np.add.reduceat(M, [0, 2])     
# indices [0,2] splits the list into [0,1] and [2] to add them separately, 
# you can see help(np.add.reduceat) for more

# array([[2, 4, 6],
#        [1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
M = [[1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [7, 8, 9]]

M[:2] = [[a + b for a, b in zip(M[0], M[1])]]

print(M)  # [[5, 7, 9], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Things to google to understand this:

- `M[:2] =`: python slice assignment
- `[... for .. in ...]`: python list comprehension
- `for a, b in ...`: python tuple unpacking loop